Movie about a girl who may have been a Girl Scout
This movie was in the 1980s or 90s. 
One scene involves a black girl who looks homeless, where the main protagonist is a man. When the man comes up to the girl, she is frightened and tries to pull out a Swiss army knife or some other Multics tool. She accidentally pulls out something else and the guy looks annoyed until she pulls a knife out. Her grandma or some lady comes out and she starts fakes crying. 
Another scene is where she is a girl scout wearing yellow and a baget hat. The guy might have been her father or he adopted her.
I think it was a father/daughter movie. There was another scene where the man and the girl have a heartfelt moment where she has to leave and they say goodbye to each other. The man  may have adopted her and she was homeless.

I'm not sure I understand. Who has the knife? The girl or the man?

The girl has the Multi tool. I think it was a Swiss army knife

Was the movie about Girl Scouts? Or was it just that the girl had on a scout uniform in one scene?

We'll work with whatever we can get on this site, but can you think of any other details? There's very little to go on here.

I think it was about a father daughter movie. There was another scene were the man and the girl where she is living with him have a heart felt moment where she has to leave and they say goodbye to each other.

@cameron: Okay, it's time to roll out the old favourites lol. IS it black and white or colour? What's the approximate age of the film? When did you see it? Any memorable lines? What did any of the characters look like? Can you remember anything else, no matter how trivial.

Color definitely and the age of the film seems to be mid 80s to early 90s and the girl had hair like this: http://blogs.sun-sentinel.com/features_fashion/files/2010/08/FrizzyFilePhotojpg.jpg

No, I forgot about it

David arquette or someone like him was on there.

Someone asked a similar question just now and found the film: Life With Mikey (AKA Give Me A Break) from 1993. It's also about a man taking in a small black girl:

Mikey Chapman (Michael J. Fox), a former child star and now a talent agent for child stars, discovers Angie Vega (Christina Vidal, in her first movie), a girl who pick-pockets for money and lives with her teenage sister and her boyfriend. Together, they try to hit it big and earn her a role on a series of television commercials.

It seems like the one you're after. She wears a baget hat and attacks him with a Swiss army knife, and later wears a yellow outfit and hat for the commercial. Here's the trailer:



